# Why do I get this warning in every Unity project"GameView reduced to a reasonable size for this system"?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Every time I hit run in my Unity project I get this warning:

```
GameView reduced to a reasonable size for this system (1121,736x630,9764)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

And is repeated over and over. It is present even in the default projects. Can anybody help me fix it? I use Unity 2020.3.28f1.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzRoi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the game window screen resolution?

**EDIT**

Click here as shown in the picture and then choose 16:9
[image]

ِAnd Welcome to the world of game development

Comment: Sorry, I am completely new to Unity. Can you tell me please how do I do it?

Comment: Good, by the way, yellow bugs do not affect the game most of the time